# how to get the value of a radio button in servlet when the name of the radio button is in expression language

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

Below is my jsp code. I want to get the value of the selected radio button in servlet but am getting null value.

```
<td><input name="${quest.questionId}" type="radio" value="${quest.option1}" />${quest.option1}</td>
```

I have tried using `request.getParameter("quest.questionId");` and `request.getparameter("${quest.questionID}");` but I still get null value.

Comment: Why would you need dynamic name for your radio button? Can you change it to static name like myradioButton something like that?

Comment: `request.getParameter("quest.questionId");` will look for paramater with `quest.questionId` and not it's Id.. Change it to `request.getParameter(quest.questionId);` , but like SMA said, you dont need to set the name from data, just hardcode the name and get the value by that name..

Comment: because it a group of radio button, made it dynamic so i can differentiate each group from the other.

Comment: for that, you've to remove the double quotes in request.getParameter like I've stated in my comment, also you need to have `quest` object in java to get it by its Id

Comment: This is an EL `${quest.questionId}` which is to be evaluated to some value. What value does it return? Look into the generated HTML code to see what HTML code actually it renders.

Answer (score 0):

in servlet you have to use the value which is reder(radio button name) in html page for request.getparameter("");